# Advanced variables in Paypal BuyNow button

Tags: html, paypal

I want to import a money value into Paypal BuyNow button i.e. not have a pricing structure.  I have an asp.net page that creates this money value from a matrix. Can I then use "advanced variables" in the Button creation process to create:
    amount
    currency_code
and then show the amount together with the BuyNow button on a Paypal html page?

Answer (score 0):

## Good guide for using ASP.net ( C# ) and paypal.

I think you can find information from this page:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers